# JAWs screen reader reading older version of button text with changing Angular string interpolation

Tags: angular, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, section508

I have a button with text that changes occasionally through Angular's string interpolation. It renders to the screen fine, but when I tab over it with JAWs it often reads out the older version of the text (whatever it said before it changed last)

eg. `<button (click)="addUser()" mat-flat-button color="primary"> Add {{ this.users.length }} {{ this.type === 'test' ? 'first type' : 'second type' }}</button>`

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

I may have figured it out, though it is not the answer I want.

I added an [attr.aria-label] to the button with the exact same text I wanted in the button, and it seemed to work. So I have a fix, but I still have no idea why that was happening.

eg <button [attr.aria-label]="myText">{{ myText }}